# Maximal number of visible vertices

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry, convex-polytopes, convex-geometry

Let $P$ be a three-dimensional convex polytope with $N$ faces; $O$ a point outside $P$. What is the maximal number $f(N)$ of vertices of $P$ which may be seen from $O$?

Comment: Maybe the pyramid over a regular polygon would be a good example.

Comment: @F.C. This shows that $f(N)\ge N$.

Comment: Oh, I see that I had somehow missed the point. But then one can truncate the top vertex and iterates this kind of truncation, adding each time 2 vertices and one face.

Comment: F.C. is right; this is clearly optimal, as a convex polytope with $N$ facets cannot have more than $2N-4$ vertices, by Euler's formula (and relation $e\geq 3v/2$).

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov so why is it optimal? So far I see the bounds like $N\le f(N) \le 2N-4$.

Comment: @FedorPetrov As F.C. mentions, you may start with a tetrahedron all of whose vertices are visible, and on each stage truncate a *top vertex* creating a new face and increasing the number of (visible) vertices by 2. (A top vertex here is a vertex such that all its three faces are visible.) So the answer is $2N-4$.

Comment: What are you taking the maximum over? All orientations and translations of 
 a fixed polyhedron $P$? All polyhedra $P$ with $N$ facets?

Answer (score 2):

Every polyhedron can be projectively transformed so that all its vertices are "beyond a single face":

[image]

Then every vertex of of the transformed $P$ can be seen from a single point outside. So, assuming that your question is asking for the maximum *over all polyhedra with $N$ faces*, your question is equivalent to "what is the maximal number of vertices of a polyhedron with $N$ faces".

And if I am not missing something, then the answer here is $2N-4$ (see also the comments below your question, or see [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1709.02021.pdf)).